# How much salinity is needed for everyone to float?

Tags: fluid-statics, physical-chemistry, estimation, density, buoyancy

Everyone floats in Dead Sea because it is so salty. Is it true in Great Salt Lake? How about Red Sea and Mediterranean Sea? Is it impossible for anyone to sink in these seas without added weight?

Comment: It is hard to answer this question. It depends on the person. Fat floats. Bone sinks. Thin people are less able to float than fat people. Are you asking about the skinniest, boniest person in the world?